# Why does svgo remove everything when minimizing an svg with symbols?

Tags: svg, svgo

Looking at svg minimization options, I found svgo https://github.com/svg/svgo
. I successfully tried it with svg generated from illustrator, however, when I run it against the following, the resulting file is completely blank.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">

  <symbol id="beaker" viewBox="214.7 0 182.6 792">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="shape-icon-2" viewBox="0 26 100 48">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

</svg>
```

I haven't been able to find a reason why this occurs.

Comment: Perhaps the symbols are not referenced.

Comment: They are not referenced, but they don't have to be referenced if this is an external file. I guess it's probably a bug on svgo.

Comment: How is svgo going to know they are referenced from an external file?

Comment: Disable `removeHiddenElements` plugin, it's the one responsible for stripping `display: none` svg elements

Answer (score 2):

> style="display: none;"

This is causing SVGO to think you don't need the block  which mean it will empty the entire file. I'm not sure how to prevent this either

Answer (score 1):

It can be prevented by passing an option to the plugin removeHiddenElems, displayNone: false